# Parse a Fri, 03 Nov 2017 09:12:46 java which shows unparsable

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Fri, 03 Nov 2017 09:12:46 this is my date format and I want to parse it using SimpleDateFormat() in java

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: I have to fetch the date and get the timezone of NewYork

Comment: Why do you want to use `SimpleDateFormat`? [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API also known as JSR-310,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with. `SimpleDateFormat` is, frankly, long outdated and notoriously troublesome.

Comment: `ZonedDateTime newYorkTime = LocalDateTime.parse("Fri, 03 Nov 2017 09:12:46", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US)) .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));`

Comment: Wouldn’t you learn more from showing us the code that gave you the “Unparsable date” message so we could hopefully pinpoint what you did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = df.parse("Fri, 03 Nov 2017 09:12:46");
    System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: This code uses troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a task of writing a feature that would be able to parse a Date String to a Date without knowing format in advance. In other words a String should be recognized as date if it is a valid date and parsed to date regardless of the format it comes in. So the solution I came up with was to have a configuration file that holds all date formats that I support. I read them one by one and attempt to parse the string with that format. If it works then great, I stop since I got my result if not I continue to the end. If all format fail then the String either is not a Date or is in unsupported format. Of course adding (and removing) supported formats does not require code modification since it is my configurationn file. Also the order of the formats is important since that way I can control wether I prefer US formats to European style or vise-versa. I wrote an article that describes the idea in more detail. Here is the link: [Java 8 java.time package: parsing any string to date](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman/). The title says that it is for java 8, but general idea is applicable to earlier versions as well.

Comment: How many data do you process this way? I am just curious and would predict bad performance if the data are big.

Comment: In practice the data from file was read into memory at start up, so all reads for masks were done in memory. Also I was using java 8 so I used the wild crds in formatting extencively so that lowers the number of different formats. All in all it was working under few thousands to 10s of thousands parsings per second and was working well. If I would have needed further performance boost, then I could have added working with threads in paralel. But I did't need it

Comment: Thanks for your info. Well, a comparison with my lib [Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/MultiFormatParser.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-net.time4j.format.expert.ParseLog-) might also be interesting for you, especially if pattern are concatenated by separator "|" in case of same locales. I consider this as more readable and also more accurate than using optional brackets (and more performant in my own tests).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "Fri, 03 Nov 2017 09:12:46" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE, dd MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.US ) 
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Avoid `SimpleDateFormat` and such.

Your input lacks any indicator of offset-from-UTC or time zone. So we parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE, dd MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.US ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "Fri, 03 Nov 2017 09:12:46" , f ) ;
```